# Ошибка при импорте XML схемы в БД - ORA-31082: invalid attribute "totalDigits"

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql

Встала задача обработки огромного количества XML файлов (>50млн) для дальнейшего разбиения их элементов по полям в БД. Выбрал Oracle DB.
Схемы есть и схемы рабочие.

Но возникла проблема: при импорте схемы выдает ошибку в данном месте:

[image: Синтакс]

С ошибкой:

> Error report - ORA-31082: invalid attribute "totalDigits" specified in declaration of "(local simple type)"

Но при этом, например, такая структура импортируется без ошибки:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Насколько я понял, ему почему-то не нравится именно `totalDigits`, хотя, судя по описанию `totalDigits` конструкция верная. Да и с учетом того, что данная схема - схема из рабочей БД.

> May be used as facet for: xs:byte, xs:decimal, xs:int, xs:integer, xs:long, xs:negativeInteger, xs:nonNegativeInteger, xs:nonPositiveInteger, xs:positiveInteger, xs:short, xs:unsignedByte, xs:unsignedInt, xs:unsignedLong, xs:unsignedShort

Comment: Попробуйте вместо int прописать integer. А 20 знаков не много ли?

Comment: @Bakhuss попробовал с integer вместо int - все также. 
Тоже думал, что 20 это как-то много, так как макс. Int - десятизначное число. 
Но подкупает именно то, что эта схема - дамп с рабочей БД...

Comment: А у вас и макс Int установлен? Может, между ними связь есть, типа, totalDigits не может быть больше чем... и по этому ошибка?

Comment: @Bakhuss Нет, я просто неправильно выразился. Максимальное же Int значение 2 147 483 648(10 символов)

Comment: А как вы регистрируете схему? Могли бы дополнить вопрос примером. Заодно  картинки замените пожалуйста xsd фрагментами как текст.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Фасет `totalDigits` вполне валиден для `xs:int`. Схема будет зарегестрирована со значением `value="20"` потому, что базовый тип `xs:int` не имеет этого фасета. Но устанавливать это значение больше 10 не имеет смысла, т.к. `xs:int` имеет ещё другое ограничение:

```
maxInclusive="2147483647" minInclusive="-2147483648"
```

Воспроизводимый пример:

```
declare
    schemaDoc xmlType := xmlType('
        <xs:schema
            xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <xs:simpleType name="itemId">
                <xs:restriction base="xs:int">
                    <xs:totalDigits value="20"/>
                </xs:restriction>
            </xs:simpleType>
            <xs:complexType name="itemType">
                <xs:sequence>
                    <xs:element name="id" type="itemId"/>
                    <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string"/>
                </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
            <xs:element name="item" type="itemType"/>
        </xs:schema>');
begin
    dbms_xmlschema.registerSchema (
        schemaurl => 'item.xsd',
        schemadoc => schemaDoc,
        local => true, gentypes => false, gentables => false
        );
    dbms_output.put_line ('schema registred');
end;
/

schema registred
```

Схема была успешно зарегестрирована, но при создании инстанции XML документа со значением превышаемым допустимый предел, возникнет ошибка:

```
declare 
    xmldoc xmlType := xmlType ('
    <item xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://xmlns.oracle.com/xdb/schemas/'||user||'/item.xsd">
        <id>9999999999</id>
        <name>my item</name>
    </item>');
begin
    xmldoc.schemaValidate ();
    dbms_output.put_line ('XML validated='|| xmldoc.isSchemaValidated());
end;
/
```

> ORA-31038: Invalid integer value: "9999999999"
>   31038. 00000 -  "Invalid %s value: \"%s\""
>   *Cause:    The text in the XML document did not represent a valid
>              value given the datatype and other constraints in the schema.
>   *Action:   Ensure that the specified value in XML documents is valid
>              with respect to the datatype **and other constraints** in the schema.